# Fresh Ubuntu install, problems with existing partitions

Tags: installation

I wish to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a clean install. I have windows XP and Ubuntu 13.04 already installed along with some files, movies on other drive.

Now, I want to erase everything, deleting all sorts of files there and then install Ubuntu 12.04 completely fresh.

Now, my current system has 5 drives with different sizes. While selecting, 'erasing disk and re-install' the next screen shows, ' the entire disk will be used'.

I tried to create/change partitions but got confused there... should I delete already existing partitions and create new ones or just re-size them?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on you whether you want to format them or not, if you do format them you will lose all the data. If you'd like to create right partitions only for Ubuntu you can read this article about required and optional partitions in Ubuntu: [DiskSpace/Partitioning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Comment: yes, I will like to keep those drives already created.. how to format them? losing data is not an issue for me since I have done a backup for all of them..